# Fibonacci Sequence detector Java

Tags: java, sequence, fibonacci

I'm having trouble with my Fibonacci number program for my Intro to Java class. It works only when I type the numbers in ascending order.

*Goal: Must use a while loop, must detect if a number is a fibonacci number, and must detect the order of the number in the sequence. If it's not a fibonacci number it must say so, and tell what numbers it's between. The program must also keep asking for an input number until a user exits*

Example of how output should be:

```
Please input a number for analysis >> 2
2 is a fibonacci number whose order in the sequence is 4
Please input a number for analysis >> 53
53 is not a fibonacci number 
However, it lies between the Fibonacci numbers 34 (order:10) and 55 (order:11)
```

**My problem: The program works only when I type the input numbers in ascending order. So for example if I input 5, it tells me it's a fib number with a seq. of 6. But when I then type in 2, it says it's not a fib number, but it lies between the Fibonacci numbers 3 (order:5) and 5 (order:6). And when I type in 55, it tells me it's a fib number. But then I can't type in any number lower than 55 without it showing incorrect input.**

I think the problem lies in the else if statement, possibly (fibnext != testnum). Or maybe the count? Can anyone point me in the direction to where the problem might be?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fibonacci
{
    public Fibonacci()
    {
        int fibhigh = 1;
        int fiblow = 0;
        int count = 2;
        int fibnext = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean quit = false;

        System.out.println("Welcome to Fibonacci Sequence Dectector");
        while(!false)
        {
            System.out.print("Please input a number for analysis >> ");
            int testnum = input.nextInt();

            if(testnum < 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter a positive number");
                continue;
            }
            while(fibnext < testnum)
            {
                fibnext = fibhigh + fiblow;
                fiblow = fibhigh;
                fibhigh = fibnext;
                count++;
            }
            if(fibnext == testnum)
            {
                System.out.println(testnum + " is a fibonacci number whose order in the sequence is " + count);
            }
            else if(fibnext != testnum) System.out.println(testnum + " is not a fibonacci number \nHowever, it lies between the Fibonacci numbers " + fiblow + " (order:" + (count - 1) + ") and " + fibhigh + " (order:" + count + ")");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *Code Snippets* are meant to be used with code which can be run by browser like HTML/CSS/JavaScript. Java code should be wrapped in *Code Sample*.

Comment: @jimtollan The homework tag is deprecated.

Comment: @jimtollan [Homework tag is deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated). What matters is if question is clear and if we can see that OP did his research (in other words, if it is not give-me-teh-codes question).

Comment: jeez -i need to stay in more!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never reset variables 
`int fibhigh = 1, fiblow = 0, count = 2, fibnext = 0;`

You should move this code snippet

```
int fibhigh = 1;
int fiblow = 0;
int count = 2;
int fibnext = 0;
```

at the beginning of loop:

```
while (!false) {  }
```

Comment: Appears I was way off on what I thought the problem was. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are never clearing fibhigh, fiblow and fibnext. This means you will always been comparing to the highest numbers each time. You should set the values to the orignal numbers before the user enters data.